# Valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) when using hash function

Tags: c, valgrind

I implemented the [djb2 hash function](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) like this:

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while ((c = *word++))
    {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
    }

    return hash % N;
}
```

Elsewhere, I'm using the hash function via this function:

```
bool check_word(const char *word)
{
    const char *word_lower = strlwr(word); // need word_lower because hash function is case sensitive
    node *iterator = table[hash(word_lower)];
    free((void*) word_lower);
    while (iterator != NULL) // traverse linked list, looking for the given word via strcasecmp
    {
        if (strcasecmp(iterator->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And also this function:

```
void fill_hash_table(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict_ptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict_ptr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // prepare char array for every word with size LENGTH + 1 because LENGTH is the guaranteed max length
    char curr_word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(dict_ptr, "%s", curr_word) != EOF)
    {
        [...]
        unsigned int table_pos = hash(curr_word);
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

where `dictionary` represents a text file that contains line separated strings, like so:

```
a
ab
abc
```

Running Valgrind yields `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)`, referring to `while ((c = *word++))`, or `word`, to be more specific.

Is there a way to avoid this?

---

The `strlwr()` function is implemented like this:

```
// returns same string but lower-cased
const char *strlwr(const char *string)
{
    char *string_to_lower = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
    for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    {
        string_to_lower[i] = tolower(string[i]);
    }
    return string_to_lower;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How the function is called is important. Specifically, what `word` is being passed in.

Comment: If `char word[word_length + 1]` is the string, then `hash` is called via `hash(word)`. The specific word being passed in doesn't seem to matter at all.

Comment: No, that's not a MVE. Is there no other code? Obviously if that is the only code then it is completely wrong as `word` contents are not set. But perhaps you have some code that sets that. Again, please provide a minimal verifiable example. If you don't know what that means then read the link please. We need to see **exactly** the code that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Make sure the word you are passing in is NUL-terminated. Otherwise, you'll read off the end, and Valgrind will notice that.

Comment: The bug is not in this function.  It is probably in the code that constructs the buffer that's passed to this function, but you haven't shown us that.

Comment: Added code to provide more information.

Comment: Are you **100% sure** that the line length does not exceed the buffer length? There is **never** a good reason to use `%s` as an input format specifier.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yes, the maximum character count is defined to be `LENGTH := 45` and no dictionary file violates this rule.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with [my test](https://gist.github.com/neldredge/ad4c50753a8e04df6a30abe13bed0ad4).  Can you actually post a *complete*, *compilable*, *runnable* example together with an input file that triggers the warning?

Comment: @skopein if that's the case then the above code should not raise any warning of that kind. Either you're wrong or you are using the function in a different place and you did not tell us enough. I would bet on the first one if I had to, reading from files doesn't always behave as expected, specially if you're reading something else in the code that you omitted.

Comment: I added another piece that might be the cause of the Valgrind message. These two pieces are the only two where `hash` is being used.

Comment: Repeating my earlier comment would be redundant :-)

Comment: @skopein compile with debug symbols (`-g`) and re-run Valgrind with `--track-origins=yes` and check what it says. It should tell you exactly what calls the function that produces the error. Attach the output here in your question.

Comment: @rici I'm relatively new to C, so I don't know what changes to the code your comment would imply. As I see it, every word **is** `NUL`-terminated.

Comment: @skop: also, there is a reason why this site asks for a [mre]. Providing little bits of information, one piece at a time, is a waste of everyone's time. In the future, please create a compilable and executable subset of your program which you have verified exhibits the same problem. That's also a good debugging technique. You'll often find that when you do that, you can identify the problem yourself.

Comment: @skop: Using a pen and paper, execute `strlwr` on a short string. Is the result NUL-terminated? (`malloc` returns uninitialised memory.)

Comment: @rici Thanks for the feedback. I also understood the problem with `strlwr` now, so thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
while ((c = *word++))
```

can only cause such a warning if you are passing a `word` that is not a correctly initialized and NUL terminated string.

The problem in your code is most likely caused by your `strlwr()` function, which is not correctly NUL-terminating the string. You exit the `for` loop at the terminator, but fail to add it to the resulting string.

The correct code would be:

```
const char *strlwr(const char *string)
{
    char *string_to_lower = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
    unsigned i;

    for (i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    {
        string_to_lower[i] = tolower(string[i]);
    }

    string_to_lower[i] = '\0'; // Ensure NUL terminator!
    return string_to_lower;
}
```

---

Secondly, I would suggest you to modify this:

```
while (fscanf(dict_ptr, "%s", curr_word) != EOF)
```

You're using `%s` as a format specifier, which is asking for trouble. You cannot guarantee that the data that is being read will not overflow the buffer.

Use a correct format specifier that includes the buffer length, like this:

```
fscanf(dict_ptr, "%45s", curr_word);
```

Or, better, use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html), which was exactly designed to read strings in a safe way:

```
fgets(cur_word, LENGTH, dict_ptr);
```

---

Lastly:

- You should check the return value of `malloc()`.
- You should avoid casting the pointer passed to `free` like this: `free((void*) word_lower)`. Any pointer is automatically converted from/to `void*`. The cast only hides a potential error in cases where the variable is not a pointer.
- You should use `unsigned` (or even `size_t`) instead of `int` if it does not make sense for the value to become negative.

Comment: @RyanHaining thanks.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the elaborate answer.